# Check iOS Version before declaring a stored property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use the new PhotosPickerItem in my SwiftUI app but this type is available only with iOS >= 16.0.
I need to make the app available for previous iOS versions as well but I don't know how to declare two different stored properties in my ViewModel depending on the iOS version considering that I can't use `if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {...}` in stored properties.

This is my code:

```
class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var noteTitle: String = ""
    @Published var noteText: String = ""
    // [...]
    
    @Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil {
        didSet {
            if let imageSelection {
                let progress = loadTransferable(from: imageSelection)
                imageAttachmentState = .loading(progress)
            } else {
                imageAttachmentState = .empty
            }
        }
    }

    // [...]
```

I need to declare the `@Published var imageSelection: PhotosPickerItem?` only if iOS 16 is available otherwise I would declare an alternative `@Published var imageSelection: UIImage()` and deal with that in my code if I have a previous iOS version.

I know that I can declare two different `class NoteViewModel` specifically for each iOS version but it would generate a lot of redundant code that I want to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: You could approach this using generics, but this may not work because of conflicting arguments (i.e. UIImage vs. PhotosPickerItem). For example, your `class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {` would transform to `class NoteViewModel<T>: ObservableObject {` and your published variable would be of type `T` rather than `PhotosPickerItem`. Now when you create an instance of your `NoteViewModel` class, it would be created something like `NoteViewModel<PhotosPickerItem>()`

Answer (score 1):

**Environment**: Xcode 14.1, Swift 5+

It's not so common to do this if statement in the class' properties, but you can *replace* your **@Published** one as a **computed property**. I usually use this approach with a *List* placed in a View, which I declare its collection in the View Model.

Please see below my suggestion:

```
class NoteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var imageSelection: Any {
            if #available(iOS 16, *) {
// PhotosPickerItem(itemIdentifier:) is a dumb call. It only served to be tested by the compiler.
               return PhotosPickerItem(itemIdentifier: "identifier")
            } else {
// Idem above.
                return UIImage(contentsOfFile: "file")
            }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't test this code block, because you extract only the piece of interest, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: Wouldn't using a computed property remove the functionality of the `Published` property wrapper?

Comment: No, and that's surprising. When you have a `List(cars, id: \.id) { } `  you can set cars as a **computed property** in the View Model, and it will work like @Published. It's very useful when you have a SearchBar or a Filter in your View, and anything else which variation demands a new *List* call.